# Loop to search files efficiently starting from last modified file

Tags: loops, batch-file

I have a folder containing around 50 subfolders (called `0001`, `0002`, `0003`... etc) and each contain hundreds of files (called `0001_132.txt`, `0002_312.txt`, `0032_152.txt`... etc), and I need to run a batch file to extract files that I haven't processed since the last run of the batch file.

The way I currently do it is saving a `.txt` file telling me the filename of the last file being extracted during the last update. Next time I run the batch file, it loops through subfolders until reaching that particular filename and then start extracting the files newer than that particular file.

I am not sure if the way I do it is good or not but it works. HOWEVER, since I have many files in the folder, each time the batch file reads all old files before extracting new ones, which causes the program to run for quite some time. So, I would like to ask, if there is any way to not loop through those old files?

The file recording the last updated files looks something like this:

```
last_update.txt: format([subfoldername]_[file].txt)
```

eg: 0001_134
    0002_213
    .
    .
    0050_241

and my batch looks something like this:

```
for /f %%a in (C:\last_update.txt) do (
  set number=%%a
  set "subfolder=!number%:~0,4!"
  set reach=0
  for /f %%x in (c:\data\subfolder\)  do (
    if %%~nx==!number! (
      set reach=1
    )
    if not %%~nx==!number! if !reach!==1 (
      DO THE EXTRACTION
    )
    set latest_File=%%~nx
  )
  echo !latest!>>last_update_temp.txt
)

del last_update.txt
ren last_update_temp.txt last_update.txt
```

Comment: This should be a regular for loop (without /f) and `!subfolder!`  variable: `for /f %%x in (c:\data\subfolder\)  do (`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the attrib command to clear the archive bit after processing your files, then you can use xcopy with /l to get a list of the new files with the archive bit set.

Here is an example - assuming the files have already been processed and new files are waiting with the archive bit set.  The last line removes all the archive attributes once the files have been processed.

All it does is in the loop below is echo the drive:\folder\filename.txt of each file with the archive attribute set, and pause.

It uses a temporary file because of the number of files being processed, which could otherwise cause a long delay.

```
@echo off
dir *.txt /aa-d /b /s >file.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.tmp) do (
rem do your task with all the files
echo "%%a"
pause
)
del file.tmp
attrib -a *.txt /s
```

Comment: Nice - there's always other ways to skin a cat!

Comment: hi, can you give a bit more detail? I am quite new in writing batch file... thank you!

Comment: I added more detail in my answer above.